# Python Unit testing backup statics

Tags: python, unit-testing, static-members, nose

I'm trying to unit test in python but I have troubles with statics attributes.
The problem is: Python doesn't backup static attributes which entails that a test acts unpredictable. Here is an example code:

```
def test1(self):
    self.assertIsNone(MyClass.var)
    Config.var = "It works"
    self.assertEquals("It works", MyClass.var)

def test2(self):
    self.assertIsNone(MyClass.var) # Fails
    Config.var = "It works really"
    self.assertEquals("It works really", MyClass.var)
```

In the given case I can avoid that with resetting the value either when the end of the first test is reached or with `setUp()` and `tearDown()` but in my situation not (it is too hard to example). I want to make the script back up all static attributes of classes automatically as I'm used to in PHP.

I run all unit tests with nose (`nosetests path_to_tests`) but I would switch the "testing framework" if I needed to.

Comment: Fwiw, it is often regarded as bad style to use global mutable data in the first place (and class attributes are global).

Comment: I cannot avoid it because the method called while running the tests changes unfortunately class attributes. I want to back up all class attributes so that every test has the same default class attributes and globals. When a test is completed all globals and class attributes should be reseted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to avoid using the setup() and teardown() functions, but for whatever the reason, what is preventing you from just building a your own pseudo-setup function?  For example:

```
def test1(self):
    MyClass.prep()
    self.assertIsNone(MyClass.var)
    Config.var = "It works"
    self.assertEquals("It works", MyClass.var)

def test2(self):
    MyClass.prep(var="whatever")
    self.assertIsNone(MyClass.var) # Fails
    Config.var = "It works really"
    self.assertEquals("It works really", MyClass.var)

def prep(self, var="temp", var2="temp2"):
    MyClass.var = var
    MyClass.var2 = var2
```

I've done this before where in certain cases I wanted an external device to my testing to disable itself.  I just built a function that would go turn it off and in whatever tests I wanted to do that in, I would just run the "prep" function to ensure the test worked.  Then if the test worked, right before finishing, I would call the prep function again to turn the device back on.

Comment: Sorry. I think you got it wrong. I need to backup the static values of all classes because the unit test calls a method that changes static values. I don't know which values it changes (because I didn't program it) I just know that it can influence the other tests. However, I avoided the problem by creating a mock class which mocks the class `Config`. It was quite time consuming but it works. I guess it is the only way.